# Running perl script from code Exception

Tags: c#, perl

I used follow code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe");
        perlStartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\ebm\\parse_ebm_log.pl";
        perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        Process perl = new Process();
        perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
        perl.Start();
        perl.WaitForExit();
        string output = perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Now I have this exception when I look in perl.MainModule:
MainModule = 'perl.MainModule' threw an exception of type

> 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' base {System.SystemException} =
>   {"Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was
>   completed"}

Target build is x64 due to previous exception in same perl.MainModule when it said cannot run x64 on x32 process (something like that)

Comment: Does Perl work by itself (not called from .Net)?

Comment: What's `C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe -V:archname` (capital `V`)

Answer (score 1):

try  adding perl in PATH Enviroment (open a new windows shell after that) along with below changes

```
ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
perlStartInfo.FileName= "perl.exe"
perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true
```

Comment: Hi, PATH is already there. I changed code but I have same problem. Thing is that I need to have 'perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true' because I'm redirecting script output to string in C#. I also tried variations on you code.

Comment: I wrote another simple script with just print function and now it's working, so memory problem is probably about perl script. Waiting for new script and if same problem happen again will post about it. Thx.